# Значение по умолчанию у родительской модели

Tags: php, yii2, ооп

есть метод:

```
public function getPaymentText($id)
{

     return self::PYAYMEN;

}
```

От класса наследуются 4 класса, нужно сделать так чтобы если есть такое значение `PYAYMEN` у данного класса, то перезаписываем то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такая штука называется позднее статическое связываение.

```
public function getPaymentText($id)
{
    return static::PYAYMEN;
}
```

Теперь если в классе наследнике объявлена константа PYAYMEN значение будет браться из нее, если нет то с родительского класса, грубо говоря.